# find Length from Integration with finding a constant

Tags: integration

A chain hanging freely under gravity between two fixed points $(x, y)$ = $(\pm \:x_0, 0)$ (where $x_0>0$) adopts the shape given by $y=\frac{1}{k}\left(\cosh (kx) - \cosh (kx_0) \right)$ for $\lvert x \rvert < x_0$, where $k>0$ is a constant. Using this expression of the curve, find the length L of the chain between $(\pm \: x_0, 0)$ in terms of $k$.

Can anyone please show me the steps of solving this question?  If someone can, please show the steps and name the method used in each step.  I would be grateful.  Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various formulas for the arclength of a curve. The first one mentioned in a typical calculus course says that the arclength of $y=f(x)$  from $x=a$ to $x=b$ is
$$\int_a^b \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\,dx.$$
In our case $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sinh kx$. Here we have used the Chain Rule and the fact that the derivative of $\cosh t$ is $\sinh t$.

Thus we find that $1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=1+\sinh^2 kx=\cosh^2 kx$. Here we have used the identity $1+\sinh^2 t=\cosh^2 t$.

I expect that you can take over from here.

Comment: How do we only get $sinh\:\left(kx\right)$ from the derivative, shouldn't we get $sinh\:\left(kx\right)-sinh\:\left(kx_0\right)$ ? and another question, in my case what is are the limits of the integration a and b ?

Comment: The $-\cosh kx_0$ part is a **constant**, its derivative is $0$. We can integrate from $-x_0$ to $x_0$. I prefer to use symmetry, integrate from $0$ to $x_0$ and multiply the result by $2$.

Comment: I think I am a bit lost, if it's possible for you to solve it on a paper and post a picture of it here that would be great. Thank you very much for helping. Just a reminder I need the find the Length which is L and find the constant which is k

Comment: I figured out the $L=2\left[\frac{sinh\left(kx\right)}{k}\right]_0^{x_0}$ is that right ? if yes then what should I do to find the constant and how should I use the limits as I don't know what $x_0$ is.

Comment: You don't need to find the constant, it is unspecified. You need to express the length in terms of the constant and $x_0$. It is a one step integration. You should calculate, I have left things almost finished. If you write a comment with the answer you got, I can tell you whether you are right.

Comment: The answer you posted is basically right. You need to do the plugging in and get $\frac{2}{k}\sinh(kx_0)$.  That's the end, we can do no more since we are not told the values of $k$ and $x_0$.

Comment: so is the final answer going to be $L=-2\:\frac{sinh\left(kx_0\right)}{k}$

Comment: No, how did the $-$ sign get in there? It is $2\frac{\sinh(kx_0)}{k}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, one more question if I am not pothering you, how to sketch the graph of L as a function of k ? I am really bad at sketching I don't how to do it, hope you can help, thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah sorry about the it's positive I don't know why I put negative.

Comment: Just pick $x_0$ arbitrary, like $1$, and calculate for a few values of $k$. Or treat it as a function of $k$ and use calculus tools.

Comment: so u mean we let $x_0 =1$ and then we let k for example equal 0,1,2,-1,-2 , and then I just put the points on the graph ?

Comment: The constant $k$ is positive. For behaviour as $k$ approaches $0$, you can take a limit, or see what your calculator gives for $k=0.001$. When $x_0=1$ the limit is $2$.

Comment: I told you I am not good at all with sketching, I have no clue what do you mean, what I understood is that I can put $x_0$=1 and then put positive variables for k (sorry for putting negative earlier didn't see it) and then find the limit ? if I did so then what should I do to sketch the graph and what are (x,y), I think if you can do it on a sheet of paper this would be much better and easier. Thank you very much for helping

Comment: Call the usual $x$-axis the $k$-axis, and call the usual $y$ axis the $L$ axis. Graph, using say $x_0=1$. For $k$ near $0$, you will have that $L$ is near $2$. Now calculate $L$ for $k=1$, $2$, $3$, maybe a few others. Join your points by a smooth curve.